# Recover propities of div after append from POST

Tags: php, jquery

first of all I apologize for my bad English and for not knowing how to look for this question ...

Currently I have a list of items inside a div, those items have the .draggable property of jquery and on top I have a search engine that extracts those items from a database which when searching replaces those items back inside the box. When doing it via $ .post and .html (data) the problem is that those items lose the property of .draggable. My question is, how do I make that after append / html those items recover that property of jquery?

```
$(".MemberList2").height($(window).height() - 20);
var dropSpace = $(window).width() - $(".MemberList2").width();
$("#dropZone").width(dropSpace - 70);
$("#dropZone").height($(".MemberList2").height());

$(".GroupContentRow").draggable({
    appendTo: "body",
    cursor: "move",
    helper: 'clone',
    revert: "invalid"
});

$(".GroupContentMemberList").droppable({
    tolerance: "intersect",
    accept: ".GroupContentRow",
    activeClass: "ui-state-default",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        $(".GroupContentMemberList").append($(ui.draggable));
        $.post("index.php", { save: "yes", id: $(ui.draggable).attr('id'), saveIn: 0 })
            .done(function(data) {
                console.log("Data Loaded: " + data);
            });
    }
});

$(".GroupContent").droppable({
    tolerance: "intersect",
    accept: ".GroupContentRow",
    activeClass: "ui-state-default",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).append($(ui.draggable));
        //alert($(ui.draggable).attr('id') + "dentro de " + $(this).attr('id'));
        $.post("index.php", { save: "yes", id: $(ui.draggable).attr('id'), saveIn: $(this).attr('id') })
            .done(function(data) {
                console.log("Data Loaded: " + data);
            });
    }
});

$('#find').on('input', function(e) {
    console.log("Handler for .change() called.");
    $.post("index.php", { find: "yes", filter: $('#find').val() })
        .done(function(data) {
            console.log("Data Loaded: " + data);
            $('.GroupContentMemberList').html(data);
        });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mofvb1q5/

Comment: Please edit your jsfiddle so it provide a runnable html example.

Comment: You'll have to run some code to make the newly-added elements draggable. Assuming they have the same class added then I'd expect running the relevant calls to `.draggable(` and `.droppable(` again from your `.done` function would do the trick. Obviously if you don't want to repeat the code, then encapsulate all that in a function which you can call both from .done() and from when your page first loads.